# Python "while" loop with an "if" statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having some troubles with an "if" statement at the begining of my "while" loop. My goal is to check if some three files are already downloaded to the workstation. If so, script is beginning next task. Otherwise, script is waiting 300 seconds and tries again to download files as long as needed to success. So far I have something like code posted below, which seemed to be working fine but results finally were wrong.

```
if not os.path.exists(somefile_1) or not os.path.exists(somefile_2) or not os.path.exists(somefile_3):
        readyToSend = 0
        while (readyToSend == 0):
            if not os.path.exists(somefile_1) or not os.path.exists(somefile_2) or not os.path.exists(somefile_3):
                print 'There are some files missing. Restarting script.'
                lgr.info('There are some files missing. Restarting script.')
                start=300
                while start > 0:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print 'Script will restart automatically in: ', start, '\r',
                    start -=1
                removePIDfile()
                execfile(r'D:\Workspace\tools\PKG_Maker\PKG_Maker.py')
            elif os.path.exists(somefile_1) and os.path.exists(somefile_2) and os.path.exists(somefile_3):
                readyToSend = 1
                print 'Restarting script not necessary. Files downloaded.'
```

I am pretty sure that using the same "if" statement twice is kind of useless, but without this, loop was starting the timer (tiny loop inside) without even checking if those files exist.

This part of code above is not working as intended. I found out that even when I can see the files on workstation, I'm getting output that some files are missing. Messed up with these "if" and "while" statements and right now (due to my low experience) I just can't figure it out...

I'm willing to learn so maybe someone is able to show me how should this be done or which part of it is ruining this.

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but you could replace your `elif` with an `else`, which handily reduces your lengthy conditionals from 3 to 2. That's a 33% savings!

Comment: Pretty sure if you just make your `if` condition your `while` condition it will do everything you want and you can remove the two `if` statements

Comment: What is `execfile` being used for? Is the script restarting itself (rather than just letting the `while` loop continue)? Why not just use e.g. `while not all(os.path.exists(path) for path in (somefile_1, somefile_2, somefile_3)):`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're both right. Idea with deleting `if` statements sounds good but you got my attention with that `while not all` loop. About the `execfile` - yes, it's restarting whole script because there are few things happening above that loop. Thanks for your responses, I'll check it out!

Comment: It would be better to reorganise the control flow to allow you to return to the start *without* `execfile` (e.g. recursively call the function an outer `while True` loop, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling three files separately when you could deal with them in the same way. I would suggest the following:

```
from os.path import exists

ready = 0
files = [somefile_1, somefile_2, somefile_3]

while not all(exists(f) for f in files):
    print 'There are some files missing. Restarting script.'
    sleep(300)
    removePIDfile()
    execfile(r'D:\Workspace\tools\PKG_Maker\PKG_Maker.py')

print 'Files downloaded'
```

This also strips the additional if statements and such. Since you have not provided any of the code from the `PKG_Maker.py` I cannot really help you further, but since it is also python it is likely you could invoke it directly from the loop instead of using `execfile`.

Comment: I've used your idea with list instead of using `if` triple times, thanks for this solution. It's simple to use with my knowledge and working exactly as I needed. About the `execfile` - I'm using this to restart this script from beginning (not only the while loop but the whole thing). I just didn't knew how to do that better and got stuck with this. What do you mean by invoking it directly from loop? You don't have to give me direct answer but any direction for me would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The `PKG_Maker` script does _something_ when you execute that. Instead of executing it using `execfile` you could load it as a library and invoke the _something_ from your code directly. This would be better because it is likely you could tell exactly when it finishes instead of waiting for 5 minutes. You could also handle any exceptions it raises directly.